# How to create partitions in Ubuntu after installation?

Tags: partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with no partitions. System created:

- `/dev/sda1` `ext4` with 228GB
- `/dev/sda2`; `extended` with 4GB
- `/dev/sda5`; `linux swap` with 4GB

I'm using GParted to make a partition in the 228GB (where Ubuntu is). However, it doesn't allow me to create further partitions. How do I create further partitions?